# Running Arduino IDE on ESP32-C3-MINI-1

Tags: esp32

I want to configure the software for the ESP32-C3-MINI-1 module but am unsure how to do so. Would this be done through the ESP32-C3-DEVKITM-1 or would there by a different RF testing board? Any help on how to get started is appreciated.

Comment: Also, is there a particular breakout pcb that I can use for breadboarding / interfacing?